# Cakephp 3 : Localization Routing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I add route like below

```
Router::connect('/:language/:controller/:action/*',
                       array(),
                       array('language' => '[a-z]{3}'));
```

I have two language `src/Locale/jp` and onother is `src/Locale/fr`

After add route configuration I have tried below `URL`

```
project/jp/tests/index
```

It's giving me error `JpController` not found.

How can I configure route for localization in cakephp 3.

Update :

In before filter I have added below code , but language is not changing

```
if($this->request->params['language']=='jp'){
      Configure::write('Config.language','jp');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a close look at what you are passing, `jp`, that's two chars, now look at your regex, it requires exactly `{3}` chars - consequently, the route will not match.

On a side note, the folder name should be `Locale`, not `local`.

Comment: I just update my question , I add Configure::write('Config.language','jp'); in before filter method in app controller. But language is not changing. 

But if I try in bootstrap.php for default it's changing.

Comment: @AlimonKarim That's because you're not using CakePHP 2.x. There is no `Config.language` anymore in 3.x. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#i18n**. Also check **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-persistent-url-parameters**.

Comment: Thank you I got it. 
It will be I18n::locale('jp'); in cakephp 3.